# How do I open X11 on Mac OS X? Is it possible to add an icon to my applications folder?

Tags: x11

How do I directly open `X11` on my mac?

How can I add the `X11` icon to the applications folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend installing [XQuartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/), which is a very nice X server for OS X.

Comment: I have X11 installed. I'm just not sure how to open it directly.

Comment: Do you mean X11 installed by `homebrew` or the like, and you're wanting to run X applications under OS X? Still the same advice; the homebrew-x11 page (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-x11) suggests installing XQuartz via homebrew (which will add the Quartz app to the Applications folder); any other X11 apps installed will use it - though I believe you'll need to launch it first before running the X application(s).

Comment: I understand your point now. I use MacPorts, so I believe the correct port is `quartz-wm`. I'll give it a try. Thanks!